# iPad Pro "HTTP_USER_AGENT" of iOS UIWebView

Tags: ios, ipad

I tested my existing iOS app on the new iPad Pro. And I found out that HTTP_USER_AGENT text of UIWebview is ...

```
Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS9_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/601.1.46(KHTML, like Gecko)Mobile/13B143
```

So,web side program react as if this device is iPhone. How can I distinguish between iPad Pro and iPhone in my server side program?

Comment: How are you getting the user agent string?

Comment: I found another app's webview sent http_user_agent as "iPad".  So, this problem is of app side. I'm going to check the differences between those two apps' code.

Comment: to l'L'I    in my php code...  echo $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By adding Launch Screen.stoyboard, this problem will be solved.

Comment: thanks for your question/answer - we are having the same issue with our iOS app.

Comment: @Keisuke Uemura Is it possible to add the launch screen without using it ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and resolved it using `WKWebView` instead of `UIWebView`. This new implementation for showing web content is the one recommended by [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WebKit/Reference/WKWebView_Ref/), as it seems that UIWebView is going to be deprecated.

One thing about this new object, is that the method for evaluating a JavaScript is asynchronous. Therefore, if you want to use a synchronous method to fetch the userAgent, you should create your own category of WKWebView as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27981872/2574066).

The code should be something like this

```
@interface WKWebView(SynchronousEvaluateJavaScript)
- (NSString *)stringByEvaluatingJavaScript:(NSString *)script;
@end

@implementation WKWebView(SynchronousEvaluateJavaScript)

- (NSString *)stringByEvaluatingJavaScript:(NSString *)script
{
    __block NSString *resultString = nil;

    [self evaluateJavaScript:script completionHandler:^(id result, NSError *error) {
        if (error == nil) {
            if (result != nil) {
                resultString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", result];
            }
        } else {
            NSLog(@"evaluateJavaScript error : %@", error.localizedDescription);
        }
    }];

    while (resultString == nil)
    {
        [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate distantFuture]];
    }

    return resultString;
}

@end
```

And the invocation is quite the same than before:

```
WKWebView *webView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
defaultUserAgent = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScript:@"navigator.userAgent"];
```