# How can I read form fields from a UIWebView site using Xamarin.ios?

Tags: c#, xamarin, uiwebview, xamarin.ios

I currenly use a webview to load a site into a native xamarin.ios app.

```
public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();
        addressTxt.Text = "192.0.0.0";
        var request = new NSMutableUrlRequest(new 
        NSUrl("http://test/"));
        request.HttpMethod = "GET";
        webview.LoadRequest(request);
    }
```

This loads the site correctly into the webview. But i need to grab a hidden field value from the page for use within the app. Is there any i can do this?

I've seen a few examples, but nothing for xamarin.ios.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to evaluate JavaScript returning needed field to get value from page in UIWebView.

```
string result = _webViewInstance.EvaluateJavascript(yourJavaScriptCode);
```

also you can see this answer [WKWebView evaluate JavaScript return value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26778955/wkwebview-evaluate-javascript-return-value)