# Is there a way to return the result of evaluateJavaScript as return value of a function in Swift?

Tags: swift, closures, wkwebview

I'm trying to write a function that runs an evaluateJavaScript, waits for the result and returns it in Swift as a func return param.
Something like this:

```swift
func getCurrentTime() -> CGFloat{
  var currentTime:CGFloat = 0.0

  webView.evaluateJavaScript("window.clock.getCurrentTime()") { (result, error) in
    guard error == nil else {
            return
        }
    currentTime = result    
  }

  return currentTime
}
```

Since this function is exposed in an API I can't have a self.currentTime var to be set within the closure. I think it would be easier for anyone who uses the API to have this method return the value

Comment: Did you check the answers to https://stackoverflow.com/q/26778955 ?

Comment: @MartinR to be honest I thought I was missing out on something and was hoping there whould be a more elegant solution to this than a while loop. I will try it out, though that answer is flaged as not working anymore on iOS 12

Comment: @MartinR Is there any update on it.